# ESP8266 can't send data to local database (XAMPP)

Tags: php, arduino, xampp, esp8266, at-command

i am doing a project, one element of this project is sending data from esp8266 to database created on xampp (local server also). Firstly, i want check how it works, so i connected my esp to computer, opened terminal on ArduinoIDE and wrote some AT commands, to connect it to the same wi-fi as my laptop, later connect to xampp server (apache) by command:

```
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","192.168.1.15",80
```

and i got response that i am connected, so i want to send some data by GET function

```
AT+CIPSEND=75
GET /dht.php?temperature=30&humidity=60 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 192.168.1.15\r\n
```

but i got response in terminal like this:

```
> GET /dht.php?temperature=30&humidity=60 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 192.168.1.15\r\n
SEND OK

+IPD,883:HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Sat, 16 Nov 2019 21:11:36 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.37 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.1 PHP/7.2.12
Vary: accept-language,accept-charset
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Language: en
Expires: Sat, 16 Nov 2019 21:11:36 GMT

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Bad request!</title>
<link rev="made" href="mailto:postmaster@localhost" />
<style type="text/css"><!--/*--><![CDATA[/*><!--*/ 
    body { color: #000000; background-color: #FFFFFF; }
    a:link { color: #0000CC; }
    p, address {margin-left: 3em;}
    span {font-size: smaller;}
/*]]>*/--></style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Bad request!
OK

+IPD,399:</h1>
<p>


    Your browser (or proxy) sent a request that
    this server could not understand.

</p>
<p>
If you think this is a server error, please contact
the <a href="mailto:postmaster@localhost">webmaster</a>.

</p>

<h2>Error 400</h2>
<address>
  <a href="/">localhost</a><br />
  <span>Apache/2.4.37 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.1 PHP/7.2.12</span>
</address>
</body>
</html>


OK
CLOSED

OK
```

Do you know whai i am doing wrong?
Here is also my dht.php code which i put in folder "htdocs" in xampp folder

```
<?php
class dht11{
 public $link='';
 function __construct($temperature, $humidity){
  $this->connect();
  $this->storeInDB($temperature, $humidity);
 }

 function connect(){
  $this->link = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','') or die('Cannot connect to the DB');
  mysqli_select_db($this->link,'projekt_it') or die('Cannot select the DB');
 }

 function storeInDB($temperature, $humidity){
  $query = "insert into dht11 set humidity='".$humidity."', temperature='".$temperature."'";
  $result = mysqli_query($this->link,$query) or die('Errant query:  '.$query);
 }

}
if($_GET['temperature'] != '' and  $_GET['humidity'] != ''){
 $dht11=new dht11($_GET['temperature'],$_GET['humidity']);
}
?>
```

PS. when i wrote in my browser http://localhost/dht.php?temperature=99&humidity=99
the new values are in my database so i think this .php code is working correctly.

Comment: try to add one more \r\n at the end of the request.

Comment: @Juraj i got the same response

Comment: you send it from Serial Monitor? it will not convert \r \n to line end characters. it will send \ and n

Comment: Yes, i send it from serial monitor, i don't know about that, so i will try to upload code to my esp and check it, thanks :)